# Как из контроллера получить доступ к id input в форме?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть созданная форма, к каждому input в этой форме приставлен свой id.
Как мне в контроллере получить id input?

```
    <?= $form->field($updateForm, 'updateEx')->textInput(array('value'=>$item['name'], 'id' => $item['id']))->label('');?>

    <a href="<?php echo Url::toRoute(['site/ex-delete', 'id' => $item['id']]) ?>" >Удалить</a>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Отправить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: В каком контроллере: в том, который рендит эту форму или который обрабатывает (или один обрабатывает)?.. Хотя, мне кажется, в любом случае, вы выбрали не ту логику — можете пояснить зачем он вам нужен?

Comment: Как бы да. Идентификатор тега к контроллеру не относится никак(